# Classifying data, and then performing linear regression on the classes

Tags: regression, classification, clustering

Is it valid to perform a classification on a data set, separate the data by class, and then perform a regression on each of the groups? The reason why I ask is that the histogram for my data looks like this:

[image]

This is a histogram where the x-axis has ranges for the response variable, and the y-axis is the count for the number of data points that fall in the range. My idea was to use a linear model for the data near 0, and a different linear model for the other data.

To separate the data into two categories, I classified a data point as "small" if the response variable is near 0, and "normal" otherwise, and I trained a different linear model for data from each category. To predict the test data, I first predicted whether it was "small" or "normal" using logistic regression, and then put it through the appropriate linear model, depending on how it was classified.

This ended up improving my accuracy by quite a bit, but I'm a little hesitant to use it. I've done some research on this topic, and the method seems to be similar to cluster regression, but I haven't come across any examples where someone used a supervised classifier to split the data.

My question is whether or not this is a valid approach to take, and if it is, whether there is any literature on it. On the other hand, if it is not a valid approach, what could I do instead?

Comment: Can you not include the left most group of individuals as a new factor in your linear model?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried that, and the results were pretty similar. I was more wondering about whether doing the classification into regression has some theoretical basis to it, or whether I basically just got lucky here.

Comment: If you did that and the results were good you should do that as opposed to what you did (or suggested). Your approach is not a good idea, since you are building two different models, where the second model is based on the first model, and both models are built on the same data, which is not good. So basically you will be overfitting.

Comment: I see, but it is true that using classification to create new factors to use for regression is a good idea sometimes then? How does creating a new factor avoid the overfitting problem?

Comment: There are related methods, such as piecewise linear regression...

Comment: @user253844 In general I would avoid it, maybe some light clustering if you really don't know how to group the data. First I would try to create categories based on domain knowledge, is there something that you can use in your data to separate these two groups (which makes sense)? As proposed by Anony-Mousse, you could also use segmented regression, at the cost of a little more complexity in the model.

Comment: Now that I think about it, the original method is sort of like segmented regression, except the data is split by a hyperplane (as opposed to cutting off at certain x-values). 

It did turn out that there was some domain specific grouping! That's definitely a lot simpler than using a classifier. Thanks for the help.